# Horizontally scale a SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, database

I have very little knowledge about how SQL Server databases are set up. But I think when you say SQL Server instance it means, it's running a server to which clients can connect and query it to write or read values.

Let's say I have a table called `Employee` that has million of rows, and I want to split the data to multiple machines each having half a million rows.

- Does this mean we have two SQL Server instances running in two different physical machines?
- Are they independent of each other? Meaning, each SQL Server instance is unaware of the other being present and each has it's own `Employee` table? If so, I guess it's up to the client to query both nodes at query time (for reads) and then merge the results. Please clarify.

Comment: A good Google search phrase for the first half would be *what is a database instance*.

Comment: in OP's defence, I'm currently studying databases and would myself not have figured out the query for _database instances_ until significantly through the unit. While Google makes it incredibly efficient to find information, it's very difficult without knowing what to look for. 2. As OP mentions little knowledge about SQL Server setups, it's safe to assume their vocabulary is similarly lacking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up until a few years ago, I would have answered “Yes, databases don’t scale out well”. You could partition data across servers, and build a view, but it was messy.

A cloud approach changes that. There are now severa relational dabatase systems that scale invisibly (both up and out), using a SQL interface.

However, the nature of your question leads me to believe that you are using a traditional system, so the traditional answe still stands. Instances are separate abstractions for collections of databases, and instances do not span hardware.

Comment: Could you take more on these new relational databases that can scale horizontally invisibly?  Could I do it with MS SQL Server?

Comment: Kind of :). Azure SQL is very close to on- prem SQL Server. 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/elastic-scale-shard-map-management

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, yes it would mean that there are two SQL Server instances running on two machines.

If you just split the data in half, and split it between the machines they would be unaware. Why is it that you would want to do this in the first place? From personal experience a million rows should be doable on a single machine.

Comment: One million is just an example that I came up with!